# What does the put command do in a typical function using the State monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, do-notation

This is an example from https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads
It's an example of using `State` monad to thread the `StdGen` value through a sequence of random numbers generating commands.
If I understand what the last `return` does correctly it should just create a *new* monad with `x` as a value. But then what does the `put g'` actually do? Why wouldn't the `g'` actually be lost?

```
getAny :: (Random a) => State StdGen a
getAny = do g <- get
            (x,g') <- return $ random g
            put g'
            return x
```

Comment: This state computation can be composed with others, so it is not 'lost'.

Comment: @pdexter, I mean being lost between `put g'` and `return x`. `return x` should creae a new instance without `g'` in it, right? Then where is `g'`? Maybe I understand what `return` does in the do-notation incorrectly? I thought it was just executing monad's `return` strategy.

Comment: `State StdGen a` represents a computation with a state vale of type `StdGen`. Just pretend there's a mutable, imperative-style variable of type `StdGen`, which is readable with the `get` action and writable with the `put x` action (`x` being the new value). The `(x,g') <- return $ random g` is IMHO an anti-pattern which is best spelled `let (x,g') = random g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused by

```
(x, g') <- return $ random g
```

This indeed create a new monadic action `State StdGen (a, StdGen)`, which is executed to extract its result `(a, StdGen)`.

The confusion arises with good reason, because the code is actually equivalent to

```
let (x, g') = random g
```

where no monadic action is built, leading to more straightforward code.
This transformation is correct in any monad, not just the `State` one.

Anyway, the technical part: the `(x, g') <- return $ random g` snippet means

```
(x, g') <- State (\g'' -> (random g, g''))
```

where we can see that the monadic action takes the current state `g''` (which has the same value as g), and then does not modify it (the `(..., g'')` part) while returning the generated value `random g` alongside it (`(random g, ...)` part).

This is a bit silly, since we do not even need to *read* `g''` since we are using `random g`!

So, we are using

```
do g       <- State (\g'' -> (g'', g''))
   (x, g') <- State (\g'' -> (random g, g''))
   ...
```

when we could instead use

```
do (x, g') <- State (\g'' -> (random g'', g''))
   ...
```

which is called in the library

```
do (x, g') <- gets random
   ...
```

---

Okay, the confusion appears to be in `do put g' ; return x`.
This is desugared into bind-notation as follows

```
{ definitions }
put g'   = State $ \s -> ((), g')
return x = State $ \s -> (x , s )

do put g ; return x 
= { definitions, desugaring }
   (State $ \s -> ((), g'))
   >>= 
   (\_ -> State $ \s -> (x , s ))
= { definition of >>= }
   State $ \s -> let (v,s') = (\s -> ((), g')) s 
                 in runState ((\_ -> State $ \s -> (x , s )) v) s'
= { beta-reduction (application) }
   State $ \s -> let (v,s') = ((), g')
                 in runState (State $ \s -> (x , s )) s'
= { beta-reduction (let) }
   State $ \s -> runState (State $ \s -> (x , s )) g'
= { runState (State y) = y }
   State $ \s -> (\s -> (x , s )) g'
= { beta-reduction }
   State $ \s -> (x , g')
```

So, the effect of `do put g' ; return x` is to modify the state to `g'` (overwriting the previous one `s`) and to yield `x` as a final value of the computation (alongside `g'`).

Comment: I am sorry for being not clear enough. By return I ment the last line. I understand what the first two lines do. Thanks for this improvement too though. That last `return x` should create a new State monad with no `g'` in it, right?

Comment: @German Note that a `State StdGen a` has no state inside, but is a state _modifier_, roughly a function `\g -> (someValueDependingOn g, newG g)`. So the `return x` indeed does not involve `g'` _but_ will get composed by the `do` notation with the `put` and the rest above, so that the whole `do` block is something like `\g -> (x, g')`, where `x,g'` are computed in terms of `g`. So `g'` is _not_ lost: the last return does not cancel the effects of the previous actions.

Comment: So the `return` in the do-notation actually is not the monads's `return` strategy but rather it also calls monad's bind strategy? I thought those returns are the same.

Comment: The return is indeed the return of the monad. But the `do a;b;c;d` uses bind to connect `a,b,c,d`. If `d` is return, `a,b,c` still matter. Note that according to the monad laws, `do x <- action; return x` is equivalent to `action` -- the return has no effect, but the action is still relevant.

Comment: Which means it's both strategies. Thank you! If you make these two comments into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose our state is being stored in a file. Here is what `getAny` is doing as expressed in a Javascript/Python-like language:

```
function getAny() {
  var g = readStateFromFile("some-path")  // the get call

  var xg  = random(g)    // returns an array with two elements
  var x = xg[0]
  var newg = xg[1]

  writeStateToFile("some-path", newg)  // same as the put function call
  return x
}
```

Here `random(g)` has to return two values, so I am having it return an array.

Now consider what happens during this sequence of calls:

```
 a = getAny()       same as:    do a <- getAny
 b = getAny()                      b <- getAny
 c = getAny()                      c <- getAny
```

for `a = getAny()`:

- the state is read from the file
- it's given to `random` which returns two values
- the second value is written to the file
- the first value is returned and stored in the variable `a`

and then for `b = getAny()`:

- the state just written to the file is read back in
- it is fed to `random()` producing a value and new state
- the new state is written to the file
- the new value is returned and stored in the variable `b`

etc...

Now to answer your questions:

> what does the put g' actually do?

It updates the state with a new value.

> Why wouldn't the g' actually be lost?

`newg` is just a local variable, so it's value would be lost unless we saved it somewhere.